# Read bundled application resource file from javascript on phonegap in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a hybrid iOS application that uses webview with phonegap and native code.

I am using the `application.plist` file in the `Resources` folder to store certain configuration items, which I use in the native code.

Is there a way, I can read the same plist file in javascript?

If that is not possible, what is the preferred method to store the config in such a way to be accessible by both native code and javascript?